# How to install/upgrade svn on SLE?

Tags: software-installation, zypper, sles

My SUSE (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)) got installed old svn. I want to upgrade it but if I download package for Packages for SLE 11 and try to install it `via zypper install subversion-1.7.5-83.1.x86_64.rpm` I get

```
Problem: nothing provides libserf-1.so.0 needed by subversion-1.7.5-83.1.i586
 Solution 1: do not ask to install a solvable providing subversion = 0:1.7.5-83.1
 Solution 2: break subversion by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

Is it ok to choose either 1 or 2 or cancel installation process and do it different way?

Comment: It already describes the problem in your error description: `Problem: nothing provides libserf-1.so.0 needed by subversion-1.7.5-83.1.i586` this means your new subversion depends on a libserf-1 package which is either not available or you only have the wrong version

Answer (score 4):

Follow instructions on http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel:tools:scm:svn&package=subversion to get the latest subverstion installed.

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:tools:scm:svn/SLE_11/devel:tools:scm:svn.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install subversion
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably find that you're going to need [serf](http://code.google.com/p/serf/) and possibly [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) installed.

> libserf or libneon  (OPTIONAL for client)
>
> ```
>      The Serf and Neon libraries both allow the Subversion client
>      to send HTTP requests.  This is necessary if you want your
>      client to access a repository served by the Apache HTTP
>      server.  There is an alternate 'svnserve' server as well,
>      though, and clients automatically know how to speak the
>      svnserve protocol.  Thus it's not strictly necessary for your
>      client to be able to speak HTTP... though we still recommend
>      that your client be built to speak both HTTP and svnserve
>      protocols.  Your client can be compiled against either
>      libserf or libneon (or both), as they offer competing
>      implementations.
> ```

I don't believe binaries exist for SLES to install these libraries, so you'll need to download and compile serf (and/or neon) from source.

After that, be sure to run `ldconfig` before attempting the SVN install again, so that the newly installed serf libraries are seen.